# Get a brokers list for Kafka AdminClient.describeLogDirs call

Tags: java, apache-kafka

The API of `AdminClient` contains the method [describeLogDirs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeLogDirs-java.util.Collection-) which needs "a list of brokers" in both signatures. The expression in quotes is exactly what the javadoc tells about it - not more.

What do I have to provide as argument for this function? My first guess was a sequence starting by 0 or 1 to replication factor, but then I saw the following (unrelated) line in the logs of my application which showed me that I probably have to expect something like `1001`.

```
13:47:11.931 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=myInstance-1725351556, groupId=] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(myexample-0)) to broker example.com:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)
```

I verified this by hard-coding `1001` for one run:

```
List<Integer> brokers = Collections.singletonList(1001);
DescribeLogDirsResult result = adminClient.describeLogDirs(brokers);
```

Now: how do I fill the variable `brokers` with live values from my kafka Client? (`Producer` and `adminClient` instances are available in my code)? I wasn't able to find any example code for this call.

**Update (Solution):** This is the final codeline which I'm using now:

```
List<Integer> brokers = adminClient.describeCluster().nodes().get().stream().map(Node::id).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`describeCluster()`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeCluster-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeClusterOptions-) in order to fetch node-specific details like host, port and id.

> `public abstract DescribeClusterResult describeCluster​(DescribeClusterOptions options)`
>
> Get information about
>   the nodes in the cluster.
>
> Parameters: options - The options to use
>   when getting information about the cluster.
>
> Returns: The
>   `DescribeClusterResult`.

Example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);
DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
Collection<Node> clusterDetails = describeClusterResult.nodes().get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. I ended up with the following line: `List<Integer> brokers = adminClient.describeCluster().nodes().get().stream().mapToInt(Node::id).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`